# Iam having windows 10 pc I restarted the pc while the update was going on the it is showing a blue screen with text "Getting Windows Ready "

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, laptop, reboot, window

Iam having windows 10 pc I restarted the pc while the update was going on the it is showing a blue screen with text "Getting Windows Ready Don't Turn off your Computer"

Comment: Wait for it to finish - may take 15 - 30 minutes. If, after an hour, nothing has happened, turn the computer off and try again.

Comment: You should be seeing spinning dots indicating it is actually busy. Could change to a progress bar at some point. If that doesn't happen after 5 minutes (the actual updating can take much longer) then its safe to assume the system halted. If your computer is normally already slow, give it 15 minutes of no spinning dots before you assume its halted. If it is halted, turn off the pc wait 5 secs and turn it on. Windows should recover normally that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you restarted after it told you to, this is normal behavior. Sometimes it takes a long time to apply the update; particularly if you do not use SSDs or M.2 drives.